# Image not rendering in react native (Expo)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am created a simple box component which takes image source as props. But while calling HomeScreenBox the image is not rendering..

```
<HomeScreenBox
      BoxName="Add Marks"
      BoxImage='require("../assets/images/person.jpg")'
 />
const HomeScreenBox = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={props.BoxImage} />
      <Text>{props.BoxName}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Try specifying width/ height in the style prop and resizeMode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

require should not be a string, try
`BoxImage={require("../assets/images/person.jpg")}`